# Pegar o input radio mais selecionados com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, testes, input, radiobutton

Estou montando um teste, só estou com a estrutura html feita, queria saber como faço para saber qual dos input radio está mais selecionado. Ex.: A maioria selecionada foi "A)" então ao enviar o formulário, é exibindo a imagem correspondente a maioria de letra "A)" e assim sucessivamente com as demais alternativas "B)", "C"), "D)" E "E)"...
 é um html bem simples...

```
1) Questão 1
</font><font size=4 color="black" face="arial"><p>
<label>
<input type="radio" name="questao1" value="a" /> A) resoposta 1 </label>
<br />
<label>
<input type="radio" name="questao1" value="b" /> B) resposta 2</label>
<br />
<label>
<input type="radio" name="questao1" value="c" /> C) resposta 3</label>
<br />
<label>
<input type="radio" name="questao1" value="d" /> D) resposta 4</label>
<br>
2) Questão 2
</font><font size=4 color="black" face="arial"><p>
<label>
<input type="radio" name="questao2" value="a" /> A) resoposta 1 </label>
<br />
<label>
<input type="radio" name="questao2" value="b" /> B) resposta 2</label>
<br />
<label>
<input type="radio" name="questao2" value="c" /> C) resposta 3</label>
<br />
<label>
<input type="radio" name="questao2" value="d" /> D) resposta 4</label>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Podes fazer isso deste modo:

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
var button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', verificar);

function verificar() {
    var resultados = {};
    [].forEach.call(inputs, function (input) {
        var letra = input.value;
        if (!resultados[letra]) resultados[letra] = 0;
        if (input.checked) resultados[letra]++;
    });
    alert(JSON.stringify(resultados, null, 4));
}
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yLgrtaw3/

Juntei um botão ao teu HTML para iniciar a verificação. Assim quando o botão fôr clicado, é chamada a função `verificar` que percorre os inputs todos e vai preenchendo o objeto `resultados`. Cada vez que encontrar um que está verificado (ie: `input.checked`) então ele soma mais um.

No final dei um alert, mas podias também fazer `return` na função e usar noutra lógica que tenhas.

Comment: Fica uma sugestão também para um HTML mais organizado: http://jsfiddle.net/yLgrtaw3/2/

Comment: Muito Obrigada, isso vai me ajudar muito! Mas como que faço para ao invés de aparecer a quantidade de alternativas selecionadas, apareça o resultado correspondente a maioria de alternativas selecionadas... Poderia até direcionar para uma pagina html onde vou criar uma para cada letra... Se a maioria for "a" o javascript direciona para uma pagina html referente a maioria de "a" lá vai ter uma imagem e mais algumas coisas que quero acrescentar... Por que assim, eu queria fazer um teste de personalidade...

Comment: @Karina é isto que procuras: http://jsfiddle.net/m3toobdk/1/ ?

Comment: Perfeito, exatamente isso!!! Muito obrigada mesmo, de coração.

Comment: @Karina de nada.